# Extjs gridpanel display 25 rows max due to localstorage proxy. How to change this limit value?

Tags: javascript, extjs, gridpanel, sencha-cmd

I have a grid panel and its code is:

```
{
            xtype: 'gridpanel',
            x: 10,
            y: 10,
            autoScroll : true,

           // height: 300,
            width: 300,
            title: 'Grid Panel',

            store: 'peopleStore',

            columns: [
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    text: 'Name'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'gender',
                    text: 'Gender'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'age',
                    text: 'Age'
                }
            ]
        }
```

My store structure is :

```
 Ext.define('ThemeApp.store.peopleStore', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

            model: 'ThemeApp.model.peopleModel',
            storeId: 'peopleStore',


            proxy: {
                type: 'localstorage',
                id: 'PeopleInfo'
           }


    });
```

I have a add row button. But only 25 rows are displayed and remaining rows goes behind these 25 rows. Does anyone knows about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When my app had a similar issue, I fixed it by setting the proxy's [limitParam](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-limitParam) to the empty string, "", which is what the docs recommend if you don't want to send a limit parameter.

It could also be a result of the store's [pageSize](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-pageSize).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Changing page size worked.
In my case I am using local storage so there is no option to set limitParam as I am not sending or receiving data to server. 
pageSiZe was the main issue.